# Adding a label to a text area which was created using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **If This question has been answered please direct me to the answer**

I am working on creating a mobile application which is a form designed based off a form which is used at my job. Part of this form will require the input of numbers which must fall within a specific range of numbers. If the numbers input fall outside that range of numbers, the user will need to input "corrective actions" at the end of the form.

I have a javascript function to "validate" these input fields. I have also been able to get the same function to generate a `<textarea>` in the correct location, but when I try to get the function to pull the content of the input field's label and add it to the generated text area the function does not work.

The following is a small portion of both the HTML form and the javascript associated with the input fields:

```
<div id="coldtemp" data-role="ui-content">

            <label for="bottomair">Maketable Air Temp (bottom)</label>
            <input data-clear-btn="true" name="bottomair" required id="bottomair" type="number" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
            <p class="tollorance"></p>
</div>

<div id="correction">

</div>
```

The javascript:

```
function coldValidate(elem) {
    var lable = document.createElement("label");
    var child = elem.parentNode.getElementByTagName("label").textContent;
    //lable.appendChild(child);
    var para = document.createElement("textarea");
    var element = document.getElementById("correction");
    var x, text;
    x = +elem.value;
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 33 || x > 40) {
        text = "Temp Out of Tolerance</p>";
    } else {
        text = " ";
    }
    elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = text;
    //element.appendChild(lable);
    element.appendChild(para);
}
```

I have tried variations on the `.getElementBy` javascript method but nothing works and I am truly stumped. I have also commented out part of the "label" code in an attempt to figure out what was going wrong, this is why the `lable.appendChild(child);` and `element.appendChild(lable);` are both commented out.

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript framework like angular or react. You could also use node, express and pug, template engine to advice this in a simpler way

Comment: No, I am currently only using native javascript and some jQuery for my form as I am not familiar with anything else at this point

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `getElementByTagName("label")`, which is invalid syntax. What you're looking for is `getElementsByTagName("label")[0]`:

```js
function coldValidate(elem) {
  var lable = document.createElement("label");
  var child = elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].textContent;
  //lable.appendChild(child);
  var para = document.createElement("textarea");
  var element = document.getElementById("correction");
  var x, text;
  x = +elem.value;
  if (isNaN(x) || x < 33 || x > 40) {
    text = "Temp Out of Tolerance</p>";
  } else {
    text = " ";
  }
  elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = text;
  //element.appendChild(lable);
  element.appendChild(para);
 }
```

```html
<div id="coldtemp" data-role="ui-content">

  <label for="bottomair">Maketable Air Temp (bottom)</label>
  <input data-clear-btn="true" name="bottomair" required id="bottomair" type="number" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
  <p class="tollorance"></p>
</div>

<div id="correction">

</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT:**

The additional problem that you're facing with the commented code is due to you attempting to set `child` variable as the `textContent` of the label element, and then append it to the label. Instead, you need to set the `child` variable as the label itself, and append it to **`element`**, rather than `lable`:

```js
function coldValidate(elem) {
  var lable = document.createElement("label");
  var child = elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("label")[0];
  var para = document.createElement("textarea");
  para.setAttribute("id", "textbox"); 
  child.setAttribute("for", "textbox");
  var element = document.getElementById("correction");
  var x, text;
  x = +elem.value;
  if (isNaN(x) || x < 33 || x > 40) {
    text = "Temp Out of Tolerance</p>";
  } else {
    text = " ";
  }
  elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = text;
  element.appendChild(child);
  element.appendChild(para);
 }
```

```html
<div id="coldtemp" data-role="ui-content">

  <label for="bottomair">Maketable Air Temp (bottom)</label>
  <input data-clear-btn="true" name="bottomair" required id="bottomair" type="number" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
  <p class="tollorance"></p>
</div>

<div id="correction">

</div>
```

Note that I have also given the new textbox an ID, and given the label a new 'for' field, which correlates to the new textbox.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I tried this correction to my code within the full page, and it does not seem to be working. When I comment out all of the lines dealing with retrieving the content of the `<label>` tag the code works like expected and produces the "Temp Out of Tolerance" message where appropriate. But as soon as I un-comment those sections the code fails to produce the "Temp Out of Tolerance" message.

Comment: Because `child` is not a node. It is a text from the label. You're trying to append the text of the label to the label itself. In order to correct that, you would need to remove the final `textContent` from `child`: `var child = elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("label")[0];`. But you shouldn't **need** to do that -- what are you trying to accomplish with those two lines of code? Are they needed at all? The 'Temp Out of Tolerance' already appears. Do you want the text 'Maketable Air Temp (bottom)' to change to the number selected?

Comment: The text area which will be generated if the number input falls out side of the preset range will be placed on a different "page" within the mobile app. I am trying to place a corresponding `<label>` tag next to the generated text area due to the fact that there are ruffly 50 different areas sections within the form which might need "corrective actions" noted within the form.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to showcase the label being moved to next to the textbox, and also associated the 'for' attribute :)

Comment: These corrections do not seem to be helping. When I took the `.textContent` off of the child variable, it started working (although producing three text areas rather than one) but now the code is not producing anything again. And now I am even more confused as to what is going wrong with my function

Comment: Have you tried logging the objects to the console? console.log("values: ", label, child, paragraphs, element); in Chome, using the inspector, this will allow you to view all values and attached functions available to each of these objects. They are listed in the order they are provided (separated with commas)